# Show non empty levels in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

How I can list levels for one dimension, which have non empty associated measure?

Let assume that I have measure Budget. We created budget four times in a year, so this measure contains all of these values. I need to check only one prediction (category) in the report.

This query returns me all levels:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Label] AS [Dim_Budget Category].[Category].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION 
MEMBER [Measures].[Value] AS [Dim_Budget Category].[Category].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 

SELECT 
{
    [Measures].[Label], 
    [Measures].[Value]
} ON 0,
{
    [Dim_Budget Category].[Category].&[BUDGET],
    [Dim_Budget Category].[Category].&[YEP_1],
    [Dim_Budget Category].[Category].&[YEP_2],
    [Dim_Budget Category].[Category].&[YEP_3]
} ON 1
FROM [Retail]
```

Now I am trying to add logic which check If category have any value in measure Budget. If yes, the query should return this level.

Comment: will the NonEmpty function not work ? you have a measure `[Measures].[Budget]` ?

Comment: Yes, but how I can include it in this query?

Comment: is it these that need testing YEP_1, YEP_2, YEP_3 ?

Comment: Yes, I need to test all category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if `[Dim_Budget Category].[Category].&[YEP_1]` is empty against a measure `[Measures].[Budget]` just wrap NonEmpty around it:

```
NonEmpty(
  [Dim_Budget Category].[Category].&[YEP_1]
 ,[Measures].[Budget]
)
```